# BufferedImage setRGB isn't accepting given values

Tags: java, swing, rgb, bufferedimage

I'm trying to paint an image using setRGB, and I go get the RGB values from a text file, however the image always paints black. But if I provide my own values, it works.

Here's the code that always paints in Black:

```
public JMenuBar menubar;
public JMenuItem importFile;
public Scanner filePath;
StringTokenizer tokens = null;
BufferedImage image;
int[][][] images;
JPanel panelDown = new JPanel();
MyPanel myPanel;
Color myColor;

int[] coords = new int[2];
int i = 0, j = 0;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        //g.setColor(myColor);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        //g.drawRect(10, 10, 40, 50);
    }
}

public Window2() {
    super("Exercise 2");
    menubar = new JMenuBar();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel panelBar = new JPanel();
    add(panelBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panelDown, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    importFile = new JMenuItem("Import", 'I');
    panelBar.add(menubar);
    menubar.add(importFile);
    importFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(Window2.this, "Import Maze", FileDialog.LOAD);
            fd.setFile(".txt");
            fd.setLocation(Window2.this.getX() + 100, Window2.this.getY() + 100);
            fd.show();
            if (!fd.getFile().endsWith(".txt")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Window2.this, "Wrong file extension", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                File theFile = new File(fd.getDirectory() + "\\" + fd.getFile());
                try {
                    filePath = new Scanner(theFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Window2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                images = readFile(filePath);
                panelDown.setLayout(new GridLayout(coords[0], coords[1]));
                for (int k = 0; k < coords[0]; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < coords[1]; l++) {
                        int red = images[k][l][0];
                        int green = images[k][l][1];
                        int blue = images[k][l][2];
                        myPanel = new MyPanel();
                        panelDown.add(myPanel);
                        image = new BufferedImage(30, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                        myColor = new Color(red,green,blue,255);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
                                image.setRGB(i, j, myColor.getRGB());
                            }
                        }
                        myPanel.repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

The images array stores these values in sets of 3 that are in a text file:

```
255   0   0     0 255   0     0   0 255
255 255   0   255 255 255     0   0   0
```

If I change this:

```
int red = 180;
int green = 50;
int blue = 170;
```

it paints in another color.

What's wrong with the code that it doesn't accept the values from the text file?

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: I'd also call `myPanel.repaint();` at the end of the `for-loop`s not wihtin it

Comment: You need to show your data loader, because currently `images[][][]` could be anything.

Comment: You may need to override the paintComponent method of myPanel or simply call myPanel.getGraphics().drawImage(image);. Remember Swing components do not repaint themselves so it may me necessary to use a some sort of loop that always repaints the image to the panel because java by default disposes of its graphics after each call. (Resulting in a black or tan-grayish background color)

Comment: @StoneAgeCoder *"by default disposes of its graphics after each call"* - I'm not sure that's entirely true - but I wouldn't trust it either way.  Also, you forget to mention that Swing is single threaded and not thread safe, so beware of your loops ;)

Comment: I deleted my answer because you changed your code.  But you still need to show what the `images` array has been set to.

Comment: OK, I was looking at the question, from one edit behind your changes.  Have you used a debugger to make sure your `images` array really does contain the values from the text file?

Comment: I didn't debug, but I printed the values after they were all stored, and they contain the same numbers as in the text file

Comment: OK, so you're making one `BufferedImage` for each value of `k` and `l`.  How are you actually displaying these?  There's nothing in the code to add these to your panel.

Comment: I was trying to save you guys the trouble by avoiding posting alot of code, but I guess it's easier that way sometimes. I'll edit.

Comment: @AdamSilva Oh maybe try using this type bufferedimage. BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB.

Comment: @StoneAgeCoder it's the same :/

Comment: @AdamSilva Yes please.  When you don't know where the problem is, making guesses at which portion of your code to post just wastes everyone's time.

Comment: @AdamSilva One thing I noticed is that k & l are always zero in the for loop. You never defined coords[0] & coords[1] as anything so they are without a value. This makes the for loop useless as there is no iterations.

Comment: @StoneAgeCoder If that were the case, the image would be red, not black.  He probably just hasn't shown us where he sets the values in `coords`.

Comment: @DavidWallace It is the case look for where he defines coords[0] & coords[1] its not there making both k & l always zero whats the point in the for loop if int k =0; & k < coords[0]; when coords[0] is not defined as an integer so by default is zero.

Comment: Yes, but he hasn't shown us the code where he reads the file and sets `images`, and I'm guessing he sets `coords` in the same chunk of code.  We shouldn't have to guess what might be in the code, of course.  But the fact remains, if the loop doesn't run, then `image` is always null.  He claims that the image is always black, which isn't the same thing.  My answer below explains what he's seeing.

Comment: ah alright. Need to learn how to refresh ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `myPanel.repaint()` over and over within the loop over `k` and `l`, with `image` set to a different `BufferedImage` each time.  The effect of that is going to be that the panel ends up with the last image that you created.

In this particular case, the last image you created is the one that's all black.

Comment: I already moved myPanel.repaint() outside the `k` and `l` loops. Now what? Should I store each BufferedImage inside an array, then paint them?

Comment: Honestly, it's not particularly clear what you're trying to achieve.  If you're trying to tile these images, it might be easier to just have one big image, with all the colours at the right spots.

Comment: I'll try to figure out the best way to do it. Thanks :)